# Fragment not able to change on run time in android

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fregment extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn,btn2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fr;

            fr=new page1();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame, fr);
            ft.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Previous",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fr;

            fr=new page2();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

            ft.replace(R.id.frame, fr);
            ft.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Next",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

this is my java Code 
in xml

```
<fragment
    android:name="in.solutiontech.example19clock.page1"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

i want to change my fragment From page1 to page 2.i also Created the page one and two if i don't give this line app not running
        android:name="in.solutiontech.example19clock.page1"
if i gave it Fragment not changing on run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the tag name “fragment” to "Framelayout" in your XML file. because the first parameter of method "replace()" is a viewid of layout container

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager(), if you are using API < 14.

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Fregment extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn,btn2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fr;

                fr=new page1();
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame, fr);
                ft.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Previous",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fr;

                fr=new page2();
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.frame, fr);
                ft.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Next",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

In the XML file you need to use the FrameLayout instead of Fragment,since you cannot just replace a statically created fragment in the activity.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Make these changes, and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take the frame as a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout and i would suggest you to use

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

instead of

```
getFragmentManager();
```

Hope this helps.